# Display list of images by image count variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this variables:

```
var imagesCount = 3;
var imageUrl = "http://www.example.com/";
var imageId = "000-000-000";
```

and I need to get a list like this:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/GetImage.aspx?cid=000-000-000&num=1" />
<img src="http://www.example.com/GetImage.aspx?cid=000-000-000&num=2" />
<img src="http://www.example.com/GetImage.aspx?cid=000-000-000&num=3" />
```

Any help please.

Comment: Are you using any MVVM frameworks like AngularJs or KnockoutJs or should this be plain jQuery/html ?

Comment: Could we see your attempts? what have you tried? what problem have you encountered?

Comment: No. Only plain js/jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (i = 1; i <= imagesCount; i++) { 
    document.writeln(imageUrl + "GetImage.aspx?cid=" + imageId + "&num=" + i + " />");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Iwill accept this in couple of minutes

Comment: A better approach is to collect all the markup in a string and thus make a single insertion

Answer (score 4):

Here implementation on JS, without jQuery.

```js
var imagesCount = 3,
    imageUrl    = "http://www.example.com/GetImage.aspx?cid=",
    imageId     = "000-000-000",
    fragment    = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    i,
    image;

for (i = 1; i <= imagesCount; i++) {
  image = document.createElement('img');
  image.setAttribute('src', imageUrl + imageId + '&num=' + i);
  fragment.appendChild(image);
}

document.getElementById('images').appendChild(fragment)
```

```html
<div id="images"></div>
```

Comment: this is the best answer so far. Efficient and no library-dependant. documentFragment is a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Just use this JS

```
    for (var i=1; i <= imagesCount;  i++){
            var img = "<img src='http: //www.example. com/GetImage.aspx?cid=000-000-000&num="+ i +" />";
            $(".yourContainerClass").append(img) ;
    }
```

Must have jquery for this to work

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

```
for(var i=1 ; i <= imagesCount; i++){
    var img = $('<img />'); 
    img.attr('src', imageUrl + "GetImage.aspx?cid=" + imageId + "&num=" + i);
    img.appendTo('#imagediv');
}
```

Comment: Variable `i` needs to start at 1, not zero.